# Find the differential of $f(A)=det(A^{-1}-A)$ where $A$ is invertible.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, determinant

The question is if $A$ is an invertible matrix with real entries of size $n$. Is $f(A)=det(A^{-1}-A)$ differentiable? and what is the differential.

I think I managed to show it's differentiable. the determinant is a polynomial. If we derive it by $A_{ij}$ we will get either a polynomial or a constant, at any rate, it will be continuous,  and so all the partial derivatives are continuous, and that implies that $f$ is differentiable.

But what is the differential?

Comment: If you know how to find the differential of the determinant and the differential of $A^{-1}$, then you can find the differential of $f$ using the chain rule.

Comment: Are you considering $A$ as a matrix-valued function of a real variable $A = A(x)$ and trying to find $\frac{df(A)}{dx}$? Or are you asking for $\frac{d f}{dA}$? I think you are asking for the latter, no?

Comment: chain rule is good, but how can i find the differential of determinant? or $A^{-1}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that 
$$
\frac{d}{dt} \det(H(t))=\det(H(t))\cdot\operatorname{trace}\!\left(H(t)^{-1}\frac{d}{dt}H(t)\right) =
\operatorname{trace}\!\left(H(t)^{\#}\frac{d}{dt}H(t)\right)
$$
where $H^\#$ is the adjoint/adjugate matrix of $H$.

Now set $H(t)=A+tX$ to compute the directional derivatives of the function and finally the gradient or full derivative.

---

One could of course first simplify the expression by noting that
$$
\det(A^{-1}-A)=\frac{\det(I-A)\det(I+A)}{\det(A)}
$$

Comment: Chain rule is good, but can you show why the differential of the determinant is the trace?

Comment: Because $\det(I+tX)=1+t\cdot\operatorname{tr}(X)+O(t^2)$. And that the linear term of this expression has this form is easy to verify from the Leibniz formula or by the product rule applied to the columns as factors in this multilinear expression.